# Nodejs variable route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I have and variable nodejs route, I'm trying to use those values in the aggrerate function of mongodb using mongoose:

```
apiRoutes.get('/val6/:_level/:location', function(req, res) {

val6.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
            {
                [req.params.location]:true

            }
    },
    {
        $sample:{size:1}
    }
],
    function(err, val6) {
        res.json(val6);
    })
});
```

When I send a postman request, i get an random item with val2 set to true

[image: Postman request]

When I add another condition to my match clause, like this:

```
$match:
{
  [req.params.location]:true,
  level:1
}
```

I get absolutely no matches, but in the same screenshot as above, the level is one. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit one**

```
$match:
{
   level:1,
   [req.params.location]:true

}
```

Switching the values seems to fix the problem (So i think it's a bug in general with computed javascript values) but leads me to the next problem that I was actually facing.

```
console.log(req.params.location);
console.log(req.params.level)
```

//logs 'val6' (location) and '1' (level)
using them inside the code like this, doesnt work:

```
$match:
{
   level:req.params.level,
   [req.params.location]:true

}
```

So hardcoded values work, but variable values don't. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: this aggregate function is of ES/mongo ?

Comment: Yes sorry I haven't been clear on that, I'm using mongodb and this indeed the mongodb arregrate function.

Comment: try multiple match statements like this - $match{[req.params.location]:true}},$match{level:1}

Comment: That won't work as well, asides from my IDE giving 'duplicate' errors/warnings, node/mongoose will match on level but not on location.